# Group_concat into group_concat with two different separators

Tags: subquery, mysql-workbench, group-concat, nested-groups

I use the follown as one movie's page

```
     SELECT 
    `mt_films`.`Title1` AS `Title1`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `t_idiotita`.`idiotita`,
        ': ',
        `t_people`.`person`
        ORDER BY `t_idiotita`.`cnt_gr_id` ASC
        SEPARATOR ' ') AS `kati`
FROM
    ((`t_people`
    JOIN (`st_peoplefilms`
    JOIN `mt_films` ON ((`mt_films`.`ID_films` = `st_peoplefilms`.`ID_films`))) ON ((`t_people`.`ID_person` = `st_peoplefilms`.`ID_person`)))
    JOIN `t_idiotita` ON ((`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = `t_idiotita`.`ID_idiotita`)))
WHERE
    ((`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 29)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 33)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 27)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 12)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 43)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 11)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 32)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 5)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 24)
        OR (`st_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 14))
GROUP BY `mt_films`.`Title1`
```

That returns e.g.

```
Title1 | Dir.: John | Script: Peter | Script: Anna | ...
Title2 | Dir.: George | Dir.: Paul | Script: Gus | ...
```

But while for many many movies work more than one person for the same specialty i need a second group_concat to group all the persons for the same specilty. I also need two different separations. The first ": " separates the specialties and the second ", " the persons

Expected result

```
Title1 | Dir.: John | Script: Peter, Anna | ...
Title2 | Dir.: George, Paul | Script: Gus | ...
```

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

ohhh great... many many thank's about your "NO HELP"!!